# Add a fadeIn / fadeOut to table results

Tags: javascript, fadein, fadeout

I have the following code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function filter(phrase, _id) {
        var words = phrase.value.toLowerCase().split(" ");
        var table = document.getElementById(_id);
        var ele;
        for (var r = 1; r < table.rows.length; r++) {
            ele = table.rows[r].innerHTML.replace(/<[^>]+>/g, "");
            var displayStyle = 'none';
            for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
                if (ele.toLowerCase().indexOf(words[i]) >= 0)
                    displayStyle='';
                else {
                    displayStyle='none';
                    break;
                }
            }
            table.rows[r].style.display = displayStyle;
        }
    }
</script>
```

The javascript is targeting this html table:

```
<body><form>
<b>Search:</b>
<input name="filt" onkeyup="filter(this, 'sf', '1')" type="text">
</form>
<br>
<table id="sf" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2">
    <tr bgcolor="">
        <td align="MIDDLE">
            <font color=""><b>First Name</b></font>
        </td>
        <td align="MIDDLE">
            <font color=""><b>Last Name</b></font>
        </td>
        <td align="MIDDLE">
            <font color=""><b>Location</b></font>
        </td>
        </tr>
    <tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <td>
            John
        </td>
        <td>
            Smith
        </td>
        <td>
            Sun
        </td>

    </tr>
    <tr bgcolor="#EAECEF">
        <td>
            James
        </td>
        <td>
            Bond
        </td>
        <td>
            Moon
        </td>

    </tr>
    <tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <td>
           Rob  
        </td>
        <td>
            Halford
        </td>
        <td>
           Mars
        </td>

    </tr>
</table>
```

I would like the table to fadeOut when user completes their search query and hits 'enter' and then the results to fadeIn.

Could anyone help me please?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Replace,

```
table.rows[r].style.display = displayStyle;
```

with,

```
if displayStyle===''{
   $('#'+_id+' tr:eq(r-1)').fadeIn();
}
if displayStyle==='none'{
   $('#'+_id+' tr:eq(r-1)').fadeOut();
}
```

Comment: This was using jQuery. Did you include jQuery library in the head of the document?

Answer (score 0):

it can be done in a nice and simple manner using [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/). if you don't use it yet, you should do.